# MongoError: $match with $text is only allowed as the first pipeline stage

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have MongoDb aggreate with search text.
but the mongoDb throw Execption, idk maybe my aggregate is wrong? or i cant use $match more than 1 time? Sorry im new with MongoDB

```
const current_date = new Date()
var two_days_ago = current_date
two_days_ago.setDate(current_date.getDate() - 2)

return Post.aggregate([
    { $match: { editorChoice: false }},
    { $match: { $text: { $search: category } } },
    { $match: { $expr: { $and: [{ $gte: ["$createdAt", two_days_ago ] }, { $lte: ["$createdAt", current_date ] }] } } },
    { $sort: {'likeCount': -1} },
    { $limit: 80 },
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'likes', 
        let: { postUid: '$_id' }, 
        pipeline: [ { 
            $match: {
                $expr: { 
                    $and: [ 
                    { $eq: ['$user_id', mongose.Types.ObjectId(user_id)] }, 
                    { $eq: ['$post_id', '$$postUid'] } ] 
                } 
            } 
        } ],
        as: 'likes' } },
    { $addFields: { isLike: { $eq: ['$likeCount', 1] } } },
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'locations',
        localField: 'location',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'location' } },
    { $unwind: {
        path: '$location',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'sticker_images',
        localField: 'sticker',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'sticker' } },
    { $unwind: {
        path: '$sticker',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'prangko_images',
        localField: 'prangko',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'prangko' } },
    { $unwind: {
        path: '$prangko',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
    { $project: aggregate_project }
]).exec()
```

but i have similar aggreate with text search but without this

```
{ $match: { $expr: { $and: [{ $gte: ["$createdAt", two_days_ago ] }, { $lte: ["$createdAt", current_date ] }] } } },
```

Its my $match wrong or something about Date variable?

Comment: you can only use $text as first pipeline in aggregate 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#restrictions

replace first 2 $match with  {$match:{editorChoice: false,$text: { $search: category }}}  and then try

Comment: also you don't need to add multiple match like above 3 you can combine them into one like in above comment

Comment: the error its fix but the data not show anything. is my Date is wrong?

Comment: replace two_days_ago with
two_days_ago=new Date(new Date().setDate(current_date.getDate() - 2))
if you console right now both dates are same

Comment: write the answer about mongodb. so i can accept the answer. @sushantmehta

Comment: I already wrote problem in mongodb  you're facing, now the issue is in js date you're creating try to console.log() both values are same you need to replace it with the date I already shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
return Post.aggregate([
    { $match: { $text: { $search: category } } },
    { $match: { editorChoice: false }},
    { $match: { $expr: { $and: [{ $gte: ["$createdAt", two_days_ago ] }, { $lte: ["$createdAt", current_date ] }] } } },
    { $sort: {'likeCount': -1} },
    { $limit: 80 },
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'likes', 
        let: { postUid: '$_id' }, 
        pipeline: [ { 
            $match: {
                $expr: { 
                    $and: [ 
                    { $eq: ['$user_id', mongose.Types.ObjectId(user_id)] }, 
                    { $eq: ['$post_id', '$$postUid'] } ] 
                } 
            } 
        } ],
        as: 'likes' } },
    { $addFields: { isLike: { $eq: ['$likeCount', 1] } } },
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'locations',
        localField: 'location',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'location' } },
    { $unwind: {
        path: '$location',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'sticker_images',
        localField: 'sticker',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'sticker' } },
    { $unwind: {
        path: '$sticker',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'prangko_images',
        localField: 'prangko',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'prangko' } },
    { $unwind: {
        path: '$prangko',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
    { $project: aggregate_project }
]).exec()
```

Comment: Some explanation or short summary highlighting the approach/issue always helps

Comment: while using $text with $mach in aggregate the $mach with $text search should be first in pipeline of aggregate or else it will not run